# Firefox addon change about:blank

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to change the `about:blank` page to the url of my firefox addon homepage page.

How do I change the default new tab url or can give a new tab a default url?

I'm using the Firefox Add-on SDK.

Comment: For reference: there is already an add-on [doing exactly that](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/new-tab-homepage/). It isn't using the Add-on SDK however, the SDK doesn't expose the necessary API - one would need to use chrome authority and do low-level stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of the [TabOpen event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) and the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) method.